# I can't get the value of input field

Tags: javascript, html, input

I have an input element in my html code and I want to access toits value but my javascript code doesn't work.
Does anyone have an answer to this ?

```js
let inputElem = document.getElementById('username');
let button = document.getElementById('input-btn');

let inputValue = inputElem.value;

button.addEventListener('click', function () {
    console.log(inputValue);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="username">
<button type="button" id="input-btn">click</button>
```

Comment: move `inputValue = ...` inside event listener

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're reading the value immediately upon loading the page, before the user has had a chance to enter a value.

Read the value in the click handler instead:

```js
let inputElem = document.getElementById('username');
let button = document.getElementById('input-btn');

button.addEventListener('click', function () {
    let inputValue = inputElem.value;
    console.log(inputValue);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="username">
<button type="button" id="input-btn">click</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the  let inputValue = inputElem.value; in to button.addEventListner
since this out side the  button.addEventListner, it is firing only at page load

```js
let inputElem = document.getElementById('username');
let button = document.getElementById('input-btn');

//let inputValue = inputElem.value;
//moved this to  button.addEventListener
button.addEventListener('click', function () {
    let inputValue = inputElem.value;
    console.log(inputValue);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="username">
<button type="button" id="input-btn">click</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem here that You're trying to access the input value before the button is clicked you need to get the value only when certain funciton is called

Ex: onclick

```js
let inputElem = document.getElementById('username');
let button = document.getElementById('input-btn');


button.addEventListener('click', function () {
    let inputValue = inputElem.value;
    console.log(inputValue);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="username">
<button id="input-btn">submit</button>
```